Pluming in ceramic logs into existing gas fireplace
We have an existing Heatilator E36 insert with a gas starter line plumbed in.
I would like to add a gas log set to the insert.
Unfortunately, we had recently re-tiled the fascia and it is not accessible to get to the back of the insert in order to plumb it in direct to the valve. I tried disassembling the insert as much as possible without breaking tile, and there's no access.
I had attempted to get the line loose at the pic to just plumb it into this junction, but given the age and amount of oxidation I'm afraid it'll just break.
My questions are:
Is it ok to run the existing fire starter with some ceramic logs on top, just for visual, not for heat?
What kind of connections is this, I assumed threaded but can't really see any threads. Any advice here?
Assuming I can bust this connection loose, would re-plumbing the new gas log set into this junction be ok? I would still have the valve at the wall. Just looking for your thoughts and what you would do.
Would you just bust the wall open from behind and plumb it in right....



Thanks in advance!

As you probably know, what you have there is a log ignitor. What I believe you're asking is if you can convert it to a decorative, ceramic log appliance. The answer is yes but if you haven't done it already you first need to look closely at the installation instructions for your Heatilator before you do any more dismantling.
  https://downloads.hearthnhome.com/installmanuals/17335.pdf     

A ceramic gas log appliance can be installed but it isn't as simple as dropping a few ceramic logs on the grate. There are a number of safety requirements that must be met. Among them are an igniter and an automatic shutoff for the gas line.
Working with gas lines is very risky if you're not experienced with it. A mistake can obviously be deadly. You need to make sure that you're meeting ANSI requirements. This job may better be left to a professional installer.
BTW - I noticed in the pictures you provided that there is a gap around the gas line as it enters the firebox. That should be sealed with a noncombustible sealer before you build any fire in that firebox. See page 19, figure 16 in the installation guide.

Thanks for the feedback, I do appreciate it.

You're welcome! If this was helpful an upvote would be appreciated. Thanks.
